# How to redirect search results to google search result in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect the search result url from my Wordpress site to the google result. When the user does a search in the search box, instead of showing the results on the site, they are redirected to the search result on google.

Example:

```
https://example.com/?s=TEXT
```

to

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com%20TEXT
```

I added the following code in FUNCTIONS. PHP but it's not working properly. It's taking too long to redirect.

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:example.com%20" . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Have you looked at your browser devtools network tab? It will record a timeline of the browser - server interactions. You can tell what's slow and even see, heaven forbid, redirect loops.

Comment: You can try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-search/